# Stream file line by line and keep progress as it goes?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, filestream

I need to read files of a variety of size from 1mb to 2gb, since the files can have a huge size I am streaming it.

- How do I know how much of the file was read and and keep track of it without having to pre-read all lines ?

Sample code

```
int count = 0;
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string item = string.Empty;
        while ((item = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            item = item.Replace("\"", ""); // remove unwanted double quotes
            if (item.Length < 2) // dont need lines with less then 2 char
                continue;

            if (fine add to db) 
                count++; // to keep track of good lines
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? You are streaming and you are keeping track via db and counter.

Comment: @TimSchmelter like the question says I want to keep track of how much of the file has been read, if the file is 2gb how would I know im near the end of it, etc ? the counters I have are not to keep track of how much it was read from the file, it is to keep track of good entries.

Comment: Maybe you find this helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35438/Asynchronous-stream-reader-with-progress-bar-suppo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `"Position"` property which is overrided by `"FileStream"` from the `"Stream"` class.

Take a look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.position.aspx)

Comment: But I do not know the amount of lines inside the file since I am streaming it, so I don't think knowing the position would help me.

Comment: Every character stores 8 bytes as you may already know. Combination of the "Length", "Position" and character size will help you to do such a thing. If you want something to say exactly the current character index, you should use a more high-level class for reading and writing process like StringBuilder or something like that. At this situation, you should calculate the base data you have. Hope it helps.

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi `Every character stores 8 bytes as you may already know` :)))

Comment: So instead I could simple track the Position and compare to the size of the file instead ? Not sure if it would work that way but if position is the current buffer then it would work to know how close I am to the total size of the current file right ?

Comment: Thanks, my previous comment worked just fine using the Position property you suggested

Comment: What is so funny @L.B?! Say it, then we all can be happy together old man. Maybe you think being wise means laughing to each other instead of motivate each other to the best. @Guapo Yes. You can simple do that. Be sure it will work as my 10 years of experience says that. In case you had any problem do not hesitate to contact me.

Comment: So I think it's not a shame and nothing is so funny here! because facebook is somewhere else as you should know the place. By the way as we have had many situations about our language, based on the UTF8 encoding, and Nvarchar datatype in the SQL it stores 8 bytes as far as I know. Now Mr Wiseman! The thing is how ever I don't know about the memory usage of one character thing, it doesn't matter. Maybe I'd never need to know because we are not in the stone age anymore AS YOU MAY ALREADY KNOW BY NOW! And the result is my answer was correct and @Guapo got it! He's more genius than you, Mr Wiseman

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi I was too lazy to get into such discaussion but your answer is also not exactly correct. Just use the OP's code and see the `stream.Position` after reading a single line. You will see that it is much more ahead than the read bytes since both StreamReader and FileStream make their own caching. BTW the question is not related with DBs and I don't see why you mention `Nvarchar` (also `as far as I know` is not very convincing)

Comment: First of all, it's "discussion" and also I agree with you in the lazy thing, cause instead of correcting me, you did start meaningless laughing. I think I'm finished here cause my wrong post is the correct answer now. You should go to the facebook if you feel alone and as @Guapo said, it worked. If you do something wrong, don't try to mess it up, because actually it's getting worst.

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi OK, test your solution with `stream.Position` and read your comments Tomorrow. Then think why you got so angry and what I said wrong. Good night.

Comment: I must also say, I saw these downvote wars many times. I just get fun.

Comment: I've had tested it about two years ago. No need to do that. Although I don't know about the memory thing, I made it done and it's still working like a charm! I'm getting angry of your chatty poor lazy act that is not nice in your age. I'm about the age of your son! I should learn from you. Go work on your character instead of solving programming things. You've forgotten the correct way of communication. Meaningless laughing like some kid makes everybody angry. Do not try to correct yourself. Take care.

Comment: You see your act is like a 5 years old kid... You have a mental problem and I'm cool with that. :)

Comment: It seems you've been through many wars!! as your character has already shown who you are... Great warrior! You're like the last samurai in the stackoverflow.com!! :)) You made my night man!

Comment: It is normal not to know everything. what horrible is that the *people* who doesn't know what he doesn't know. I would advice to test it again(`I've had tested it about two years ago`). And I tried to keep my politeness till now. But it may not go on forever.

Comment: I know nothing and I'm proud that I'm not like you, but I do believe that you owe me an apology about the meaningless laughing. I was polite until you did the kiddy thing and you know that! It's not technical anymore and don't try to correct yourself and make it through the other way. We both know who did the thing. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19414/discussion-between-mohammad-goudarzi-and-l-b)

Comment: For your laughing wise man. It's not technical anymore as I said. At least respect yourself. I'm an idiot yeah, but even me as an idiot know that your move was wrong. I don't know what to call you that you can't understand the wrong and right. :D

Comment: By the way, hey wise man, try learn some english... :D "Idiotness" is not an english word. Where are you from originally?! ;))

Comment: OK lets start a new beginnig. I'll learn english and you learn basic concepts of computers and programming.

Comment: I know nothing about the programming if it makes you happy. A new beginning means **instead of laughing to someone who doesn't know something, teach them how to deal with the concept.** it's the matter of the stackoverflow.com. Mocking the others is not a success, sharing the knowledge you have is not a lost. :)

Comment: You are repeating yourself. If you don't have anything new to say just post as `""`.

Comment: You know the little thing that is inside our head keeps us from saying things we shouldn't? I think you don't have one of those. Also be sure that you are not my age and my type (as a character) for having a conversation (as it's not already!). You are a WISE MAN! A great mind like Anstain, a great warrior! and finally you know all the things that Bill Gates wishes to know about the "Basic concepts of Programming" discussion. You are already an A+!! MCSD! MCPD!! Everything... So I'm not your type. Because (as your politeness! said, I'm already an idiot with a correct answer) :) God bless you.

Comment: **Why being wrong makes you so angry?** everybody makes mistakes. the problem with you is that it is hard for you to accecpt to be wrong after then years of experience (and possibly your collegues think you are genious :))

Comment: I'll go to sleep now. Let's finalize  it as `Every character stores 8 bytes as you may already know ` **ha ha ha**

Comment: Yeah! you're right. I said it about a hundred times that I don't know anything about programming, if you know the meaning of **hundred** word!! :D By the way, the answer is 'No', they don't think so, cause the one and only @L.B the great said I'm an **idiot with a correct answer that he down voted** cause he was thinking about the basic concept of Programming **while he was laughing at me**! :D))))) Then he started to be a wise man, a warrior, who knows everything about the basic concepts. Something to say again?! Wise man. :{ :P

Comment: No! it depends on encoding. I don't know where I heart that, I think he was an OLD WISE MAN who said it! he was a warrior of stackoverflow wars!! :)))))))... :P

Answer (score 0):

```
var remaining = yourFile.Length;
var goodLines = File.ReadLines(yourFile.FullName)
                    .Select(line => line.Replace("\"", ""))
                    .Where(line => line.Length > 1);

foreach(var goodLine in goodLines)
{
   // do something with goodLine

   // this will be slightly off since you remove quotes.
   remaining -= (goodLine.Length + Environment.NewLine.Length);
}
```

[MSDN File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but that would break the not pre-reading the file requirement and I would rather not to have 2gb pilled on my memory.

Comment: A good approximation but not exact. `yourFile.Length` includes `\r\n` but `goodLine` not.

Comment: @Guapo: `File.ReadLines()` streams and will not "pre-read" the entire file.

Comment: @AustinSalonen yes, however you are storing all the data on goodLines which would be the same thing.

Comment: @Guapo:  Where is that happening?  Nothing is stored in this implementation.

Comment: @AustinSalonen how is that so ? you read all the lines into goodLines then iterate thru it.

Comment: @Guapo:  `File.ReadLines` is lazy and there's no `To...` to evaluate anything; `File.ReadAllLines` would do exactly as you describe.